# Symfony 1.4/ Doctrine; n-m relation data cannot be accessed in template (indexSuccess)

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

I have a database with 3 tables. It's a simple n-m relationship. Student, Course and StudentHasCourse to handle n-m relationship. I post the schema.yml for reference, but it would not be really necessary.

```
Course:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: course
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    StudentHasCourse:
      local: id
      foreign: course_id
      type: many

Student:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: student
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    registration_details:
      type: string(45)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    name:
      type: string(30)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    StudentHasCourse:
      local: id
      foreign: student_id
      type: many

StudentHasCourse:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: student_has_course
  columns:
    student_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    course_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    result:
      type: string(1)
      fixed: true
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Course:
      local: course_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    Student:
      local: student_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
```

Then, I get data from tables in executeIndex() from the following query.

```
  $q_info = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->select('s.*, shc.*, c.*')
   ->from('Student s')
   ->leftJoin('s.StudentHasCourse shc')
   ->leftJoin('shc.Course c')
   ->where('c.id = 1');
  $this->infos = $q_info->execute();
```

Then I access data by looping through in indexSuccess.php. But, in indexSuccess I can only access data from the table Student.

```
<?php foreach ($infos as $info): ?>
  <?php echo $info->getId(); ?>
  <?php echo $info->getName(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I expected, that I could access StudentHasCourse data and Course data like the following. 
But, it generates an error.

```
<?php echo $info->getStudentHasCourse()->getResult()?>
<?php echo $info->getStudentHasCourse()->getCourse()->getName()?>
```

The first statement gives a warning;

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Doctrine_Collection' does not have a method 'getCourse' in D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear\symfony\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php on line 64

And the second statement gives the above warning and the following error;

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\sam\test_doc_1\apps\frontend\modules\registration\templates\indexSuccess.php on line 5

When I check the query from the Debug toolbar it appears as following and it gives all data I want.

```
SELECT s.id AS s__id, s.registration_details AS s__registration_details, s.name AS s__name, s2.student_id AS s2__student_id, s2.course_id AS s2__course_id, s2.result AS s2__result, c.id AS c__id, c.name AS c__name 
FROM student s LEFT JOIN student_has_course s2 ON s.id = s2.student_id LEFT JOIN course c ON s2.course_id = c.id 
WHERE (c.id = 1)
```

Though the question is short, as all the information mentioned it became so long. It's highly appreciated if someone can help me out to solve this. What I require is to access the data from StudentHasCourse and Course. If those data cannot be accessed by this design and this query, any other methodology is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you didn't define an n-m relationship, but two 1-n relationships. This is quite equivalent from a database point of view, but from the application point of view, you are getting 4 methods that do not have much semantic value, when you could get two easy-to-use methods : `Student::getCourses()` and `Course::getStudents()`

Read [this § of the doctrine1.2 documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/ru#relationships%3ajoin-table-associations%3amany-to-many) to learn how to achieve this. `StudentHasCourse` should be used as your `refClass`

**UPDATE**
I just understood you were storing the result in `StudentHasCourse`
To get what you want, try something like this in your controller:

```
$this->courses = CourseTable::getInstance()
  ->createQuery('c')
    ->innerJoin('c.StudentHasCourse shc')
        ->where('shc.student_id = ?', $student_id)
        ->execute();
```

This means you still need the StudentHasCourse relation in the Course class. Recover it if you deleted it.

Now you should be able to do something like this in your template

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($courses as $course): ?>
  <li><?php echo $course //implement __toString in Course ?> : <?php echo $course->getStudentHasCourse()->getFirst()->getResult(); ?></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your information greg0ire. It would help me to solve the problem. I'll check it and let you know.

Comment: I did as you have mentioned. I could create the access methods _getCourses()_ and _getStudents()_. Given a `student id`, I could get the courses followed. Yet, I couldn't get the result of `StudentHasCourse` class. Though there is a _getResult()_ in above class I didn't find a way to get it. What I finally require is a result like; `course_id, course_name, result` (from association table) given a `student_id`. It's highly appreciated if you could elaborate your answer if possible to achieve this. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Thanks again for your support. I'll check your approach and let you know.

Comment: Thank you for the help @greg0ire. But the problem persists; gives the above warning when try to access _getResult()_ `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Doctrine_Collection' does not have a method 'getResult' in D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\PEAR\pear\symfony\escaper\sfOutputEscaperObjectDecorator.class.php on line 64`. It would be a problem at my side, if you have done above and got the correct result. If so, please help me to find out it. Otherwise I further have to look into it.

Comment: Of course I didn't test anything I wrote above: I'm not going to set up a test project and a database just for you, am I ? And I make mistakes. Here, for instance, though the request should restrict the `studentHasCourse` to one element, `studentHasCourse is still` a collection, on which you should use get first. Do this and check that the collection does have only one element, I'm not 100% sure. I updated my answer with what I fell is correct.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot. Your answer was detailed and easy to understand. I got the result that I wanted from your answer. Sorry, if I have mentioned anything harsh in the above comment. I didn't mean it. I just thought that you have previously done something like this and helping me by that experience. That's what I tried to mention.  I further need to dig into doctrine as I'm just a beginner and lack of knowledge put me in trouble. Thanks again for your time and sharing knowledge.

Comment: no problem, I think I was a bit worked up because yesterday, someone tried to make me download his project through megaupload :s When I answer, I almost never search my projects, I search my memory directly, which means that people have to make up with the few errors I produce.

Comment: Your answer was error free. I just copy, pasted and it worked. :)